# Determining elements and subsets of a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let A := {1, {1}, {2}}
Which statements are true?
a) {1} is an element of A
b) {1} is a subset of A
c} {{1}} is a subset of A

I think a is true, because {1} is listed in A. c is the one giving me the most trouble, why is there two sets of brackets? What does it mean?

Comment: {{1}} means the set whose only element is {1}.

Comment: So what is {{1}} in correspondence to A?

Comment: A subset, because it is a set that contains  {1} as element, and you have asserted that it is also an element of A.

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time with this, just to clarify, {1} is an element of A. {{1}} is the set consisting of {1} which is the set consisting of 1. And all 1, {1}, and {{1}} are elements as well in A?

Comment: No, {{1}} is not an element of A, it is a subset of A

Comment: Remember that sets can be elements too.  The outermost braces indicate that what it contains are listing or describing the elements in the set. The set $H=\{a,b,c\}$ contains the element $a$ as well as the element $b$ as well as the element $c$. This is regardless of whether $c$ is itself a primitive or a set itself. Here, $a$ is an element of $H$, $\{a\}$ is a subset of $H$ and $\{b\}$ is a subset of $H$. Now, if you replace $a$ by $1$, and replace $b$ by $\{1\}$ you have your original question.  It so happens that in this specific case $\{1\}$ is both an element and a subset, merely a fluke.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following variant of your question:

*Let $A=\{1,\heartsuit,\{2\}\}$. Which statements are true? a) $\heartsuit$ is an element of $A$ b) $\{1\}$ is a subset of $A$ c) $\{\heartsuit\}$ is a subset of $A$*

I think you'll agree that all three statements are pretty clearly true. Indeed, b) and c) are almost identical questions: $1$ and $\heartsuit$ are different objects, but that difference has no bearing on whether b) and c) are true. (And, for that matter, $\{1,\heartsuit\}$ is also a subset of $A$.)

Now your actual question is exactly the same as this question, except with $\heartsuit$ replaced by $\{1\}$ (so that, in particular, $A=\{1,\{1\},\{2\}\}$). Again, all three statements are true; and again, b) and c) are almost identical: $1$ and $\{1\}$ are different mathematical objects, but that has no bearing on the fact that both $1$ and $\{1\}$ are elements of $A$, and therefore both $\{1\}$ and $\{\{1\}\}$ are subsets of $A$. (And, for that matter, $\{1,\{1\}\}$ is also a subset of $A$.) *The fact that there is* some *relationship between the two objects $1$ and $\{1\}$ is irrelevant to the question!*

Clearly the question was designed to be a little confusing (so don't feel bad about that); remember that confusion that makes us understand better after we're done being confused is really helpful to our learning.